# Deleting characters in arrays while converting rows to integer in DataFrame

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, type-conversion

I have a dataframe like below

[image]

Each row has a different length.

I'm trying to run the code below

```
for i in range(len(df)):
  df['ColumnA'][i] = df['ColumnA'][i].astype(int)
```

I'm getting an error because some rows have like "64B", "64A" string values.

For example,

```
df['ColumnA'][37]
```

Output:

```
array(['34', '35', '36', '38', '39', '40', '41', '56', '58', '59', '60',
       '61', '62', '62A', '62B', '63', '64', '65', '88', '90', '94', '98'],
      dtype='<U3')
```

You can easily see the '62A', '62B' string values.

**My goal** is to convert all strings to int **(e.g from 62A to 62)**. Deleting the characters next to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sub` function in the builtin [regex module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to replace every non-digit character (`\D` selects non-digits in a regex) with a blank `""`.

A list comprehension will let you apply that same method to every item in the list.

The last component you need is the [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) method in pandas that will apply the same function to every item in a series.

```py
import re

import pandas as pd


# sample data
df = pd.Series([
    [61, '62a', 70, 'z8z8z'],
    [61, '62hello', 70],
], name='columnA').to_frame()

# show sample data
df
#>                 columnA
#> 0  [61, 62a, 70, z8z8z]
#> 1     [61, 62hello, 70]

# select the column and apply the function to each element
df.columnA.apply(
    lambda row: [
        int(re.sub("\D", "", str(x)))  # cast to string, replace any non-digit character, cast to int
        for x in row  # for every item in the list
    ]
)
#> 0    [61, 62, 70, 88]
#> 1        [61, 62, 70]
#> Name: columnA, dtype: object
```

This will result in a list stored as each item in the Series "columnA". If you want these to be numpy arrays instead, you can wrap the list comprehension in a call to `np.array`.

Comment: Thanks to this question people can easily implement `non-digit character (\D)`. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

you can do this by using list comprehension too:

```
import re
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'colA': [np.array(['34A', '35', '36A', '38', '39', '40', '41', '56', '58', '59', '60',
       '61', '62', '62A', '62B', '63', '64', '65', '88', '90', '94', '98'],
       dtype='<U3') for _ in range(10)]})

print('before : \n', df)

df['colA'] = [[int(re.sub('[^0-9]','', el)) for el in row] for row in df['colA']]

print('after : \n', df)
```

output:

```
before : 
                                                 colA
0  [34A, 35, 36A, 38, 39, 40, 41, 56, 58, 59, 60,...
1  [34A, 35, 36A, 38, 39, 40, 41, 56, 58, 59, 60,...
2  [34A, 35, 36A, 38, 39, 40, 41, 56, 58, 59, 60,...
3  [34A, 35, 36A, 38, 39, 40, 41, 56, 58, 59, 60,...
4  [34A, 35, 36A, 38, 39, 40, 41, 56, 58, 59, 60,...
5  [34A, 35, 36A, 38, 39, 40, 41, 56, 58, 59, 60,...
6  [34A, 35, 36A, 38, 39, 40, 41, 56, 58, 59, 60,...
7  [34A, 35, 36A, 38, 39, 40, 41, 56, 58, 59, 60,...
8  [34A, 35, 36A, 38, 39, 40, 41, 56, 58, 59, 60,...
9  [34A, 35, 36A, 38, 39, 40, 41, 56, 58, 59, 60,...
after :
                                                 colA
0  [34, 35, 36, 38, 39, 40, 41, 56, 58, 59, 60, 6...
1  [34, 35, 36, 38, 39, 40, 41, 56, 58, 59, 60, 6...
2  [34, 35, 36, 38, 39, 40, 41, 56, 58, 59, 60, 6...
3  [34, 35, 36, 38, 39, 40, 41, 56, 58, 59, 60, 6...
4  [34, 35, 36, 38, 39, 40, 41, 56, 58, 59, 60, 6...
5  [34, 35, 36, 38, 39, 40, 41, 56, 58, 59, 60, 6...
6  [34, 35, 36, 38, 39, 40, 41, 56, 58, 59, 60, 6...
7  [34, 35, 36, 38, 39, 40, 41, 56, 58, 59, 60, 6...
8  [34, 35, 36, 38, 39, 40, 41, 56, 58, 59, 60, 6...
9  [34, 35, 36, 38, 39, 40, 41, 56, 58, 59, 60, 6...
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. mrCopicat. Both answers are working.